# Is it possible to make my indicator automatically change its input options while I change symbol(currency)?

Tags: pine-script

I've already tried it with If-else and syminfo.tickerid but failed(

```
if syminfo.tickerid("BINANCE:ATOMUSDT")
    Inst = "BTCUSDTPERP_OI"
 else
     if syminfo.tickerid("BINANCE:AVAXUSDT")
        Inst = "AVAXUSDTPERP_OI"
```

Maybe I did something wrong or there is another way to do it, help me plz if you have any idea how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `:=` operator when giving a new value to a mutable variable.

`syminfo.tickerid` is not a function but a built-in variable. It returns a `simple string`. So, you should use the `==` operator to compare its return value.

So, it should be:

```
Inst = ""
if syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:ATOMUSDT"
    Inst := "BTCUSDTPERP_OI"
 else
     if syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:AVAXUSDT"
        Inst := "AVAXUSDTPERP_OI"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! But I have used "Inst" in "security" function? and now have an error : "Cannot use mutable variable as an argument of the request.security funtion". Maybe there is another way to do it?

Comment: Well, the `symbol` argument of the `security()` function expects a `simple string`. You cannot really use a mutable variable there. You can use user inputs instead.

Comment: I'm a bit dumb in coding... didn't get... should I add another input, like input.symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ELSE-IF for making this work. Below is the official syntax recommended by tradingview for using else-if. Trading view doesn't allow assigning value to a variable more than once.

Based on your query:

```
Inst = if syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:ATOMUSDT"
    "BTCUSDTPERP_OI"
else if syminfo.tickerid == "BINANCE:AVAXUSDT"
    "AVAXUSDTPERP_OI"
```